# scanner.useDelimiter not working on web based CSV file

Tags: java, csv, pojo

So I am a beginner with Java and I am having a hard time learning so please be easy. I am working on a solution that would take the users input of UK currency and find the exchange rate for a user input country. Don't know that I am on the right track or not but below is the code for after the user inputs the currency amount and country to convert to. I am needing to read a web based CSV file and parse in into a POJO but I can not get the in.useDelimiter to work.

```
public static Double findExchangeRateAndConvert(String currencyType, double amount) throws IOException {


        URL url = new URL("https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/842362/exrates-monthly-1119.csv");
        try (var in = new Scanner(
                new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())))) {


            var line = "";
            in.useDelimiter(",");
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                line = in.nextLine();

                System.out.println(line);

                if (line.contains(currencyType)) {
                    System.out.println("I found it.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                }

            }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: If you're reading whole lines, you don't need to use a comma as a delimiter

Comment: I would suggest using something like Jackson ObjectMapper to parse csv to POJO, though

Answer (score 0):

Use your scanner to read a line at a time, and then split the line based on regexp. Line by line processing is a good approach as it simple to understand what is happening.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Double d = Main.findExchangeRateAndConvert("USD", 12);

    System.out.println("d=" + d);
}

public static Double findExchangeRateAndConvert(String currencyType, double amount) throws IOException {


    URL url = new URL("https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/842362/exrates-monthly-1119.csv");
    try (var in = new Scanner(
            new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())))) {


        var line = "";
        in.useDelimiter(",");
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            line = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println(line);

            String[] splitLine = line.split(",");
            if (splitLine[2].equals(currencyType)) {
                System.out.println("I found it.");
                return Double.valueOf(splitLine[3]);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}